# How to parse and deserialise api data which has multiple responses

Tags: c#

This is the data I am getting from the api.

```
[{"SectionName":"kothagudem12345","CircleName":"patny1234567890","Division":"paradise1234567","SubDivision":null,"LocationName":null,"City":"hyderabad123456","IsActive":1.0,"IsDeleted":0,"returnMessage":null,"Id":127.0,"CreatedBy":null},

{"SectionName":"section ds","CircleName":"circle ds","Division":"division ds","SubDivision":"sub ds","LocationName":"loc ds","City":"city ds","IsActive":1.0,"IsDeleted":0,"returnMessage":null,"Id":90.0,"CreatedBy":null}]
```

I used following code to get this data from api

```
string geturl = "http://192.168.0.60/mdaswebservices/api/inventory/section/";
string json = client.DownloadString(geturl);
```

For Single Response i.e given below, I'm able to parse and deserialize

```
{"SectionName":"SECTION1","CircleName":"Malkajgiri","Division":"Malkajgiri","SubDivision":"Vasanthapuri ","LocationName":"Malkajgiri","City":"Hyderabad","IsActive":1.0,"IsDeleted":0,"returnMessage":null,"Id":2.0,"CreatedBy":null}
```

My code for parsing single response

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
```

How to parse and Deserialize multiple responses so that I can store each of the response into model class below

```
public class Section
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public string SectionName { get; set; }
        public float? IsActive { get; set; }
        public float? IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public string LocationName { get; set; }
        public string DivisionName { get; set; }
        public string SubDivisionName { get; set; }
        public string CircleName { get; set; }
        public string CityName { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: try -
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Section>>(json);

Comment: im getting error at ..Jobject o=new jobject.parse(json);Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object:

Comment: Try replacing JObject with JArray. i.e. - JArray o = JArray.Parse(json);

Answer (score 0):

Your desired class doesn't match the json exactly, there's a couple of properties named differently.

You can either change your class to match the JSON:

```
public class Section
{
    public double Id { get; set; }
    public string SectionName { get; set; }
    public double IsActive { get; set; }
    public int IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public string Division { get; set; }
    public string SubDivision { get; set; }
    public string CircleName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    public object returnMessage { get; set; }
    public object CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

OR annotate the properties with `JsonProperty`

```
public class Section
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string SectionName { get; set; }
    public float? IsActive { get; set; }
    public float? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public string DivisionName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("SubDivision")]
    public string SubDivisionName { get; set; }
    public string CircleName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("City")]
    public string CityName { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you can use:

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Section>>(json);
```

Comment: I have changed my class Still im getting as "Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object:  " At Jobject o =new  jObject.parse(json); line

Comment: Remove that bit. Do just `var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Section>>(json);` as per my answer

Answer (score -1):

just cast the response, to the `list` type like below.

```
List<Section> sections = new List<Section>();
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string geturl = "http://192.168.0.60/mdaswebservices/api/inventory/section/";
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(geturl).Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    sections  = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Section>>().Result;
}
else
{
    sections = new List<Section>();
}
```

and you have the data in the `sections` now, if the status was `200 OK`